# Simulating a Waiting line

Tags: java, queue

I've been tasked as an assignment to make a queue, that is supposed to be simulated 10 times, and for it to have a waiting room that can hold 100 customers.

I was able to simulate it 10 times, but the assignment mentions criteria such as having an average waiting time of x minutes, having a minimum number of served customers, and at the end have a maximum number of those waiting in line.

Here are my classes

Customer.class

```
public class Customer {
    int arrivalTime;
    int transactionTime;
    int customerNumber;
    
    public Customer(int a, int t, int c) {
        arrivalTime = a;
        transactionTime = t;
        customerNumber = c;
    }
    
    public int getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }
    
    public int getTransactionTime() {
        return transactionTime;
    }
    
    public int getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }
    
}
```

WaitLine.class

````
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

public class WaitLine {
    private static QueueInterface<Customer> line;
    private static int numberOfArrivals;
    private static int numberServed;
    private static int totalTimeWaited;
    public WaitLine() {
        line = new LinkedQueue<Customer>();
        reset();
    }
    public final void reset() {
        line.clear();
        numberOfArrivals = 0;
        numberServed = 0;
        totalTimeWaited = 0;
    }
    public  void simulate(int duration, double arrivalProbability, int maxTransactionTime) {
        int transactionTimeLeft = 0;
        for (int clock = 0; clock < duration; clock++) {
            if (Math.random() < arrivalProbability) {
                numberOfArrivals++;
                int transactionTime = (int) (Math.random() * maxTransactionTime + 1);
                Customer nextArrival = new Customer(clock, transactionTime, numberOfArrivals);
                line.enqueue(nextArrival);
                System.out.println("Customer " + numberOfArrivals + " enters line at time " + clock
                        + ". Transaction time is " + transactionTime);
            }
            
            if(transactionTimeLeft > 0) {
                transactionTimeLeft--;
            }else if(!line.isEmpty()) {

                Customer nextCustomer = line.dequeue();
                transactionTimeLeft = nextCustomer.getTransactionTime()-1;
                int timeWaited = clock - nextCustomer.getArrivalTime();
                totalTimeWaited += timeWaited;
                numberServed++;
                System.out.println("Customer " + nextCustomer.getCustomerNumber() + " begins service at time " + clock + ". Time waited is " + timeWaited );
            }
        }
    }
    public  void displayResults() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number served = " + numberServed);
        System.out.println("Total time Waited = " + totalTimeWaited);
        double averageTimeWaited = ((double)totalTimeWaited) / numberServed;
        System.out.println("Average time waited = " + averageTimeWaited);
        int leftInLine = numberOfArrivals - numberServed;
        System.out.println("Number left in line " + leftInLine);
    }
}```


I am currently stuck on meeting the criteria described, I put the simulate function in a loop that looped 10 times and after that I used displayresults, but my results did not fit the criteria.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.
````

Comment: Do you have Java Software Structures by John Lewis and Joseph Chase? This assignment should be in the book line for line

Answer (score 0):

`transactionTime` is handled in the main method/simulation(s) and not on the customer instance itself. Yo just need the `arrivalTime` and `departureTime`, and the constructor only needs to be `Customer( int arrives )`. Then you just need `getArrivalTime()` `setDepartureTime(int time)` and `totalTime()`

Then use `import java.util.*;` with `Queue<Customer> line = new LinkedList<Customer>()` and from there you just need the main method using that queue and the customer class that I modified above.